# Handle ServerResponse WebFlux

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, reactive-programming

I want to perform some logic after RouterFunction is complete, and use ServerResponse here.
How to implement it in appropriate way?
For example:

I tried to solve it with HandlerFilterFunction  in that way -

```
  public HandlerFilterFunction<ServerResponse, ServerResponse> addMetrics() {
    return (request, next) -> next.handle(request)
            .doOnNext(response -> meterService.addMetric(response));
}
```

But this does not work. .doOnNext method is not executed

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/6.0.4/reference/html/web-reactive.html#webflux-fn-handler-filter-function

Comment: Make sure you applied your handler to the corresponding route. If you need global handler - look at `WebFilter` instead

Comment: You need to subscribe (or block or similar) to it to actually execute doOnNext

Comment: @Alex Yes , It is correctly applied. But unfortunately .doOnNext is still ignored

Comment: @grekier but this chain is subscribed  and triggered when request to my endpoint is performed. Or I'm wrong ?

Comment: just created a small example and filter is correctly applied. `route(GET("/test"), request -> ok().build()).filter(addMetrics());` probably double check your configuration